# Can't the weak force be explained purely by electrostatics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, weak-interaction, electroweak

Again, super naive, but my basic question is: isn't the force of attraction between electrons and protons sufficient to explain their confinement to atomic orbitals. I know the W and Z particles have been discovered and I know about the electroweak interaction, but what exactly do the W and Z bosons do? I mean, there must be a significant amount of positive vs negative charge between electrons and protons anyway and, as far as I'm aware atoms with one neutron are unstable. So the question is, why the W and Z bosons, what's their purpose?

Comment: In addition to the clear answer by Salvatore, the existence of certain symmetries in quantum field theory necessitates the existence of a separate force mediated by three massive bosons (the $Z^{0}$ and $W^{\pm}$). If you are interested, you can look over the [Weinberg-Salam model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction)
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weak force is not required to keep electrons confined in atomic orbitals. For that, electromagnetism is sufficient.

The weak force is different from electrostatic, and this is evident from the fact that neutrinos participate in weak interactions. Neutrinos can't interact with photons (directly), as they are uncharged: but neutrinos (as massive leptons, like electrons) carry weak charge, so they can interact with the $W^{\pm}$ and $Z$ interactions. Without weak force, you wouldn't have interactions of neutrinos with matter: as an example, the decay $\mu\to\nu_\mu+e+\bar\nu_e$ is a weak process, and cannot be explained by electrodynamics. Weak force mediates some nuclear processes, like the decay of a neutron in a proton.